# Pipes and Redirection home output

Tags: c, linux, grep, pipe, redirect

```
#include<errno.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>

int main(void) {
pid_t childpid;
int fd[2];

if (pipe(fd) == -1) { /* setup a pipe */
    perror("Failed to setup pipeline");
    return 1;
}
if ((childpid = fork()) == -1) { /* fork a child */
    perror("Failed to fork a child");
    return 1;
}
if (__________) {/* env is the child */

    if (dup2(fd[1], __________) == -1)
        perror("Failed to redirect stdout of env");
    else if (____________________) /* close unused file descriptor */
        perror("Failed to close extra pipe descriptors on env");
    else {
        execl(__________); /* execute env */
        perror("Failed to exec env");
    }
    return 1;
}
if (dup2(fd[0],__________) == -1)
/* grep is the parent */
    perror("Failed to redirect stdin of grep");
else if (____________________)
    perror("Failed to close extra pipe file descriptors on grep");
else {
    execl(__________); /*execute "grep HOME"*/
    perror("Failed to exec grep");
}
return 1;
}
```

i figured out most of the gaps but i couldn't seem to get the others to work the way  as intended. So basically, this program is meant uses redirect to implement env | grep HOME, which prints out my home directory. I am to use dup2 and excel, but need the gaps filled using c and linux system calls.

Comment: What are these gaps? Is it your homework?

Comment: the gaps are the lines, and no it is not homework, just some practice examples. for the line if (dup2(fd[1], __________) == -1, i figured the gap must be just 1, and for if (dup2(fd[0], __________) == -1), the gap would be 0.

Comment: the gaps are essentially just small calls missing, like either creating a pipe with the given info, or wherfe it says for a child, you would fork a child but set it to compare to -1 so that the error line would kick in

Comment: Take some good looks at [pipe](http://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe) [dup2](http://linux.die.net/man/2/dup2) and [fork](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork) manuals, you should success to find your answers.